# Is it possible to keep a bookmark, even after having replaced the corresponding text?

Tags: microsoft-word

Good morning,
In my company we have created a script, based on a Word template, containing a bookmark called "ProjectName". In the document, it more or less looks as follows:

```
Name         Value
...          ...
Project Name <to be filled in>  // the bookmark is on this entry
```

The problem is: many people remove the entry `<to be filled in>` and type the name of their project, and as a result the bookmark seems to be removed too.

Is there a way to keep the bookmark on that spot, even when its content has been removed and replaced by something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Consider using a Content Control

You can *tag* a Content Control. The Content Control remains there after typing.

If you *need* a bookmark, putting one around a Content Control will retain the bookmark when the Content Control is used. This is because your typing is done inside the Content Control which is inside the bookmark.

I suspect that you will not need a bookmark, though.

Here is Greg Maxey's [page on Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) and [my writing on using mapped content controls to repeat data within a document](http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart).

On the Windows version of Word, you can find Content Controls on the Developer Tab. *If you are on a Mac, write back because Content Controls are trickier on a Mac. They work but must either be inserted using the Windows version or using vba.*

### Bookmarks, Possibly With a MacroButton Field Prompt

The [MVP page on Working with Bookmarks (vba)](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm) distinguishes between Placeholder and Enclosing bookmarks. It points out that with a placeholder bookmark (an empty bookmark) a macro will insert text after the bookmark and will delete the bookmark if it already contains text (an Enclosing bookmark). You are using an Enclosing Bookmark.

If you do not replace all of the text enclosed in a bookmark, you will not replace it. However, few users have that discipline, especially when usually bookmarks are not visible. If you wanted, you could place the bookmark around a [MacroButton Field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#MacroButtonField) Prompt followed by a space. When the prompt is clicked on, it selects the prompt but not the extra space. Typing replaces the prompt but the bookmark would not be deleted.

[image: screenshot of MacroButton Field Prompt]
[image: screenshot after typing]

Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c15nt492cyrlpt8/deleteme%20MacroButton%20Field%20Prompt%20inside%20bookmark.docx?dl=0) with that construction.

If you want to explore this further, write back. However, bookmarks remain fragile. I recommend the Content Controls but do not know exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Here is information from the [MVP page on Inserting Information in a Bookmark Without Deleting the Bookmark](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InsertingTextAtBookmark.htm). That is a macro or vba page. The conclusion, there is that using a macro, the same thing happens and the bookmark is deleted. They show how to recreate it using the macro.